# WF4 - Composite custom activity throw an strange exception when using OutArgument

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation, workflow-activity

I'm trying to use a composite custom activity that apply a regular expression and return a boolean if it match.
The pattern is something encoded in design time.
The source text is coming from an activity. This activity is also specified in design time (I've made a activity designer that allow to drop an activity as source)

But I also need to return what sub string match the expression, so I added an OutArgument to retrieve the string that match, and the string captured.

Here is the code:

```
public class RegularExpression : NativeActivity<bool>
{
    [RequiredArgument]
    public string Pattern { get; set; }

    public OutArgument<string> Captured { get; set; }

    [RequiredArgument]
    public Activity<string> RetrieveTextActivity { get; set; }

    protected override void CacheMetadata(NativeActivityMetadata metadata)
    {
        metadata.AddChild(this.RetrieveTextActivity);
    }

    protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
    {
        if (this.RetrieveTextActivity != null)
            context.ScheduleActivity<string>(this.RetrieveTextActivity, this.onRetrieveComplete);
    }

    private void onRetrieveComplete(NativeActivityContext context, ActivityInstance completedInstance, string result)
    {
        var regexp = new Regex(this.Pattern);
        var match = regexp.Match(result);

        this.Result.Set(context, match.Success);
        if (this.Captured != null)
            this.Captured.Set(context, match.Value);
    }
}
```

If I execute this activity *without* binding a variable to the Captured argument, it works as expected (the Result is correctly set).
But if I use the designer to add a variable, then I bind the variable to the Captured argument this error popup:

> The argument of type 'System.String' cannot be used.  Make sure that
>   it is declared on an activity.

The exception is thrown when executing this line:

```
this.Captured.Set(context, match.Value);
```

Does someone have an idea why I can't set the argument ?
I also read that I shouldn't test that Captured is null, the runtime should automatically set a default value. But If I don't test, I've a NullReference when I don't bind a variable to the argument...

EDIT:
I want to add more information about the workflow itself. I've read in [another topic](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wfprerelease/thread/298861e2-3535-4961-b7b5-3b3275958cca/) that it *may* be VS. Here I just want to specify that I'm using a rehosted designer to create the workflow (and *not* VS). The workflow is then saved as XML in a database.
When I need to start a new workflow, I read the database, use XamlService.Load and Run the created workflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the error go away if you declare the argument in `CacheMetadata`?

```
protected override void CacheMetadata(NativeActivityMetadata metadata)
{
    metadata.AddChild(this.RetrieveTextActivity);

    RuntimeArgument argument = new RuntimeArgument("Captured", typeof(string), ArgumentDirection.Out);
    metadata.Bind(this.Captured, argument);
    metadata.AddArgument(argument);

}
```

EDIT: I was too quick. The above code should now compile and hopefully fix your problem.

Comment: I can't do that it doesn't compile:  
  
Error 27 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Activities.NativeActivityMetadata.AddArgument(System.Activities.RuntimeArgument)' has some invalid arguments     
  
Error 28 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Activities.OutArgument<string>' to 'System.Activities.RuntimeArgument'

Comment: I've edited to add a small bit of info about the workflow (dunno if it can help you to know where is the problem). Ty

Comment: At first sight it works !! Do you have any explanation on why this is needed ? Why for InArgument I don't need this ?
Now I'll spend some time to fully test then I'll mark as answer. Ty!

Comment: @Fabske You need the same piece of code for InArgument<T> as well. You don't have it in this Activity but if you're using it in another activity and it works, you probably didn't override CacheMetadata. The base implementation takes care of InArgument and OutArgument properties, so you could also call `base.CacheMetadata(metadata)` to resolve your problem instead. If you're referring to the Pattern property, it's not really InArgument<T> so you don't need to declare it to the runtime.

Comment: Inded about InArgument it was for other activities, not this one. when I replace the Runtime code by the call to the base I get this error in design time: http://tof.canardpc.com/view/a425a371-c373-4f28-9ebd-660d01c8d15d.jpg

Comment: Ok the error above is because I was calling base method first, then AddChild. The call to base must be the latest. 
So everything is fine now, your solution is working but calling base method is better for me. Thank you for your help !

Comment: The above code won't compile because the parameters are in the wrong order. It should be: RuntimeArgument argument = new RuntimeArgument("Captured", typeof(string), ArgumentDirection.Out); and metadata.Bind(this.Captured, argument);

Answer (score 2):

My problem went away when I just called the base.CachMetadata(metadata) after my adds.  Try:

```
protected override void CacheMetadata(NativeActivityMetadata metadata)
{
    metadata.AddChild(this.RetrieveTextActivity);
    base.CacheMetadata(metadata);
}
```

You want to do it after your adds, because you want the base class to know what you've added when you call it.  I think the base class uses reflection to do Damir Arh's answer for you automatically.  This way you don't have to add or modify all that code every time you add or modify your properties.  If you had a lot of properties it would become a pain real fast.

Comment: It was specified in the comments, but you're right to put it as an answer to emphases this, as it's important to reuse the base method to ensure consistency.

Comment: Oh I see the comment now that you made me curious enough to dig harder for it. 
 In my web browser, that comment was buried under a "show more comments" link.