# How I can get '*' characters instead of any string in InArgument<string>

Tags: c#, string, exception, workflow-foundation-4, execute

I have a property 'Text' that stores any text, or a password.
When the property contains a password, I need to display  the characters '*' instead of the password.
I have a view in which there is an ExpressionTextbox associated with this property.
Everything is well displayed, but on execution I get an error: The argument of type 'System.String' cannot be used. Make sure that it is declared on an activity

Here is the code:

```
private InArgument<string> _text; 

public InArgument<string> Text
{
    get
    {
        if (Model.HideValue)
        {
            return new string('*', Model.Text.Length);
        }

        return _text;
    }
    set => _text = value;
}

....

protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
{
    Model.PopulateText = PopulateText.Get(context); // here I get an error

    base.Execute(context);
}
```

So, how I can get '*' symbols instead text when is value type is password?

Comment: The implicit operator of InArgument<T> expects a constant T I think https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activities.inargument-1.op_implicit?view=netframework-4.8 . Since it is also not best practice to return a mask which gives away the number of characters in a password, why not try with a const number of `*` characters, like `return "********"`

Comment: Oguz Ozgul, I tried, I get the same error

Comment: Hey, found this which is said to apply to both InArgument and OutArgument. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551971/wf4-composite-custom-activity-throw-an-strange-exception-when-using-outargumen

Answer (score 0):

Use SecureString Class for the Password Field. Instead of masking the field